# Mssql query problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL Database and the following tables

WHE

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Item No_ | Bin Code | Quantity |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | K2-3-3   | -2       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | C2-2-4   | 3        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | K2-3-3   | 5        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | K2-3-3   | 1        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | C2-2-4   | -1       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | K2-3-3   | -10      |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | C2-2-4   | 7        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | K2-3-3   | 3        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0000955  | C2-2-4   | 8        |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Item

```
+----------+--------+
| Item No_ | Desc   |
+----------+--------+
| 0000054  | Spring |
+----------+--------+
| 0000087  | Ring   |
+----------+--------+
```

When i execute a query

```
select [Bin Code],
sum([Quantity])
from dbo.[whe]
where [Item No_]='0000955'GROUP BY [Bin Code]
```

Get returned results

```
+----------+----------+
| Bin Code | Quantity |
+----------+----------+
| K2-3-3   | -3       |
+----------+----------+
| C2-2-4   | 17       |
+----------+----------+
```

But I need something like this to work

```
select  we.[Bin Code],
sum(we.[Quantity]),
it.[Item No_],
it.[Desc],
from dbo.[whe] as we,
dbo.[item] as it
and it.[No_]=we.[Item No_]
```

I would want something like this as a result

```
+-----------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Item No_ | Desc   | Bin Code | Quantity |
+-----------------+--------+----------+----------+
| 0000955         | Valve  | K2-3-3   | -3       |
+-----------------+--------+----------+----------+
| 0000955         | Valve  | C2-2-4   | 17       |
+-----------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

But the query is not executable and getting the error like

> Column 'dbo.Item.No_' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: can u pls post expected output as well ??

Comment: If you want to select columns when using GROUP BY, they either need to be a part of the GROUP BY clause or in an aggregate function (example: SUM). Or you need to rethink your approach and maybe consider the window function version of SUM.

Comment: Your expected result please. And your query have > 2 bugs: `,` before **from**; `old style join`; last `and` must change to `on` (if you keep old style join then `where`); bad aggregate `sum` . To be continue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below query if you want to show the desc column .

```
select t1.[Bin Code],t1.[Quantity],t1.[Item No_],t2.[Desc] (select [Bin Code],
sum([Quantity]) as [Quantity],[Item No_]
from dbo.[whe]
where [Item No_]='0000955'GROUP BY [Bin Code],[Item No_] ) t1
left join dbo.[Item] t2
on (t1.[Item No_]=t2.[Item No_])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Item No_` and `Desc` added to the output, you must include them in the `group by` as the error stated.

```
select [Item No_], [Desc], [Bin Code], sum([Quantity])
from dbo.[whe] w
inner join dbo.[Item] i
 on w.[Item No_] = i.[Item No_]
group by [Item No_], [Desc], [Bin Code]
```